# How can i get text from display none Element using java selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, displaytag

[image]

I need to get text of the element in an image but that element is not displaying on a web page.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, and give id to your element

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 String text= executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML");
```

as earlier @Andreas mention be more descriptive. Good luck. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JS. It is not depends on what is element state either it is visible or not

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3716Tfxt']"));
String text = (String) js.executeScript(“return arguments[0].text;”, element);
```